# Why can I view page source but the page loads blank?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My RewriteRule is:

```
RewriteRule   ^m/watch/([0-9]+)$   /m/watch.php?v=$1   [NC,L]
```

When I try to go to http://www.example.com/m/watch/555 the page is loaded as white space but when I click view-source all of my code is there. Why does this happen?

If I try to skip the rule and go to http://www.example.com/m/watch.php?v=555 the page loads fine.

.htaccess file

```
# block access to ini
<Files ~ "\.ini$">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>

ErrorDocument 404 /not_found.php

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

#redirect to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^brocktv.ca$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.brocktv\.ca\/$1" [R=301,L]

RewriteRule   ^team$   team.php   [NC,L]
RewriteRule   ^team/$   team.php   [NC,L]

RewriteRule   ^involved$   involved.php   [NC,L]
RewriteRule   ^involved/$   involved.php   [NC,L]

RewriteRule   ^home$   home.php   [NC,L]
RewriteRule   ^home/$   home.php   [NC,L]


RewriteRule   ^m/watch/([0-9]+)$   /m/watch.php?v=$1   [NC,L]
RewriteRule   ^m/watch/([0-9]+)/$   /m/watch.php?v=$1   [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^watch/([0-9]+)$ watch.php?v=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^watch/([0-9]+)/$ watch.php?v=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule   ^isff$   ISFF.php   [NC,L]
RewriteRule   ^isff/$   ISFF.php   [NC,L]

RewriteRule   ^renderthis$   renderthis.php   [NC,L]
RewriteRule   ^renderthis/$   renderthis.php   [NC,L]

RewriteRule   ^oweek$   oweek.php   [NC,L]
RewriteRule   ^oweek/$   oweek.php   [NC,L]

RewriteRule   ^new$   new.php   [NC,L]
RewriteRule   ^new/$   new.php   [NC,L]

RewriteRule   ^m/shows$   /m/shows.php   [NC,L]
RewriteRule   ^m/shows/$   /m/shows.php   [NC,L]

RewriteRule   ^m/categories$   /m/categories.php   [NC,L]
RewriteRule   ^m/categories/$   /m/categories.php   [NC,L]

RewriteRule   ^m/social$   /m/social.php   [NC,L]
RewriteRule   ^m/social/$   /m/social.php   [NC,L]

RewriteRule   ^m/contests$   /m/contests.php   [NC,L]
RewriteRule   ^m/contests/$   /m/contests.php   [NC,L]

# temporary redirect for jobs
RewriteRule   ^jobs$   http://www.busu.net/get-involved/jobs   [R,NC,L]
RewriteRule   ^jobs/$   http://www.busu.net/get-involved/jobs   [R,NC,L]

# 480 weeks
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=290304000, public"
</FilesMatch>

# compress the files
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/x-javascript
# removes some bugs
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent

Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^brocktv.ca$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.brocktv.ca$
RewriteRule ^elections\/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.brocktv\.ca\/elections\.php" [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^brocktv.ca$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.brocktv.ca$
RewriteRule ^isff$ "http\:\/\/www\.brocktv\.ca\/ISFF\.php" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Can you provide more of your .htacess or URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I go to the site /m/watch/1 I get:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.brocktv.ca/m/watch/css/style.css?v=0.02"style.css?v=0.02
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.brocktv.ca/m/watch/js/libs/modernizr-custom.js"modern...stom.js
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.brocktv.ca/m/watch/js/mylibs/helper.js"helper.js
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.brocktv.ca/m/watch/js/libs/modernizr-custom.js"modern...stom.js
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.brocktv.ca/m/watch/js/mylibs/helper.js"helper.js
GET http://www.brocktv.ca/mediaplayer/jwplayer.js?_=1316396612274
MBP is not defined
[Break On This Error] MBP.scaleFix();
1 (line 81)
GET http://www.brocktv.ca/m/watch/js/mylibs/helper.js?_=1316396612766

404 Not Found       148ms   
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.brocktv.ca/m/watch/js/mylibs/helper.js?_=1316396612766"helper...6612766
MBP is not defined
[Break On This Error] yepnope({test: Modernizr.mq("(min-..., nope: ["js/libs/respond.min.js"]});
```

Also, when I remove the `class=class="no-js"` I see something. I think you have rewrite rules that conflict with CSS or JS file that cause the site to be "hidden"

for example the css file included is: `css/style.css?v=0.02`, maybe it should be: `/css/style.css?v=0.02`

Comment: Found the issue. Some of the files were using the wrong path because of the URL rewrite. I just added the full path to all the files and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, you are welcome. Nice .htaccess btw another quick tip: you can use **RewriteRule   ^home(\/?)$   home.php   [NC,L]** instead of creating twice the same line